# How to execute a SQLite query everyday at a particular time?

Tags: android, sqlite, alarmmanager, android-jobscheduler

Earlier I have been using alarm manager to schedule my query to execute at a particular time (exactly at 2.30 AM) everyday. As alarm manager no longer serves the purpose, I have been looking out for ways to solve this problem. With some research I came across Job scheduler, but I am not able to find a way to schedule a job at a particular time with this API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AlarmManager` to set the time at which you want to execute the SQL query and schedule the alarm as a job using the JobScheduler. You can specify the interval time with JobScheduler so you don't need to set the alarm as repeating.